# ¿Como subir varias imagenes al servidor y a la base de datos?

Tags: php, html

estoy trabajando en un proyecto pero tengo un problema, lo que quiero hacer es registrar las imagenes subidas por el usuario en una carpeta individual; el codigo es el siguiente.`

```
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <label class="w3-label w3-text-brown">Titulo del Reporte:</label>
           <input type="text" class="w3-margin-4 w3-input w3-border w3-sand" name="title" required>
           <label class="w3-label w3-text-brown">Tipo de dan&#771o:</label>
           <select list="tipo" class="w3-select w3-margin-4 w3-border w3-sand" name="tipo" required>
           <datalist id="tipo">
             <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion.</option>
             <option value="1">Contaminacion.</option>
             <option value="2">Tala de arboles.</option>
             <option value="3">Maltrato Animal.</option>
             <option value="4">Trafico de animales.</option>
             <option value="5">Incendio Forestal.</option>
             <option value="6">Desperdicio de Agua.</option>
             <option value="7">Otro.</option>
           </datalist>
           </select>
           <label class="w3-label w3-text-brown" title="Para obtener la latitud, ubique en el mapa el lugar del delito.">Latitud:</label>
           <input type="text" style="width:100%;" title="Para obtener la latitud, ubique en el mapa el lugar del delito." id="latitud" class="w3-margin-4 w3-input w3-border w3-sand" name="latitud" value="kdjfd" onfocus="blur();" required>
           <label class="w3-label w3-text-brown" title="Para obtener la longitud, ubique en el mapa el lugar del delito.">Longitud:</label>
           <input type="text" style="width:100%;" title="Para obtener la longitud, ubique en el mapa el lugar del delito." id="longitud" class="w3-margin-4 w3-input w3-border w3-sand"  name="longitud" value="ldkfd" onfocus="blur();" required>
           <label class="w3-label w3-text-brown">Descripcion:</label>
           <textarea class="w3-input w3-border w3-sand w3-margin-4" name="description" required></textarea>
           <label class="w3-label w3-text-brown">Imagenes(<small><i>Si es que las tiene</i></small>):</label>
           <input type="file" name="img1" class="w3-input w3-sand w3-border w3-margin-4">
           <input type="file" name="img2" class="w3-input w3-sand w3-border w3-margin-4">
           <input type="file" name="img3" class="w3-input w3-sand w3-border w3-margin-4">
           <label class="w3-label w3-text-brown">Aque otras instancias a notificado(<small>separe con una coma</small>):</label>
           <input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-4 w3-sand" name="estancias">
           <input type="submit" name="submit" class="w3-btn w3-grey w3-margin-8" value="Enviar Reporte">
           <center><h6><b>Recuerda TU DENUNCIA ES ANONIMA!</b></h6></center>
        </form>
```

Los que yo quiero hacer es subir las imagenes si una condicion se cumple, y que esta se guarde en una ubicacion especifica. este es el codigo php
`

```
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $lat = $_POST['latitud'];
    $lng = $_POST['longitud'];
    $desc = $_POST['description'];
    //estas son las imagenes que quiero subir
    $img1 = $_POST['img1'];
    $img2 = $_POST['img2'];
    $img3 = $_POST['img3'];
    $estancias = $_POST['estancias'];
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d");


        $caracteres = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //posibles caracteres a usar
        $numerodeletras=10; //numero de letras para generar el texto
        $code = ""; //variable para almacenar la cadena generada
        for($i=0;$i<$numerodeletras;$i++)
        {
            $code .= substr($caracteres,rand(0,strlen($caracteres)),1); /*Extraemos 1 caracter de los caracteres 
        entre el rango 0 a Numero de letras que tiene la cadena */
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO reports (code_segui, title, tipo, latitud, longitud, description, img1, img2, img3, estancias, fecha) VALUES ('$code', '$title', '$tipo', '$lat', '$lng', '$desc', '$img1', '$img2', '$img3', '$estancias', '$fecha')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            $dirmake = mkdir("reports/$code", 0777);
            //Quiero que se guarden las imagenes bajo la ruta reports/$code
            //si la condicion se cumple
            header('Location:reports_send.php?c='.$code);
            ob_end_flush();
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te voy a dejar una función de `php` que mueve ficheros, imagenes, videos, etc.

```
     $nameImagen =  $_FILES['getImagen']['name']; // cogemos el nombre de la foto (incluido su extension)
     $url = './img/img_noticias/'.$nameImagen;  //url que se guarda en la base de datos
     $nameImagen = '../../../../../img/img_noticias/'.$nameImagen; // url donde se guardan las imagenes

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['getImagen']['tmp_name'], $nameImagen)){
        echo "El archivo ha sido cargado correctamente.";

     }else{
        //Notificacion de que el error es en la foto.
        echo "Ocurrió algún error al subir la foto. No pudo guardarse";
     }
}
```

Te explico:

> `$_FILES ['nombre en el formulario']['name];`

estas recogiendo el nombre que te del fichero (Y SU EXTENSIÓN) del lado cliente (formulario)

> `$url = './img/img_noticias/'.$nameImagen;`

Esta variable ira directamente a la base de datos. En mi caso hago la conexión desde la raíz, por eso ponga esta ruta.

> `$nameImagen = '../../../../../img/img_noticias/'.$nameImagen;`

En esta variable pondremos la ruta donde queramos guardar la imagen que hemos recogido. (TEN EN CUENTA QUE ES DESDE DONDE ESTE EL CÓDIGO PHP QUE ESTAS EJECUTANDO).

> `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['getImagen']['tmp_name'], $nameImagen`

Con esta funcion de PHP le decimos que nos mueva el archivo/imagen/etc. a la ruta que le hemos indicado en `$nameImagen`.